# Php, wait 5 seconds before executing an action

Tags: php

I have a .php script that I use for creating the list of my products.
I am on shared hosting, so I can't do a lot of queries otherwise I get a blank page.

**This is how I use my script now:**

```
script.php?start=0&end=500&indexOfFile=0  ->> make a product0.txt file with first 500 products

script.php?start=501&end=1000&indexOfFile=1 ->> product1.txt file with another 500 products

script.php?start=1001&end=1500&indexOfFile=2 ->> product2.txt file with last 500 products
```

How can I modify the script so it will make all these files automatically, so that I don't have to change each time the link manually?

I would like to click a button which will do this:

make the `product0.txt` file with the first 500 products

wait 5 seconds

make the `product1.txt` file with with another 500 products

wait 5 seconds

make the `product2.txt` file with the last 500 products

Comment: In less than the time it took you to write this, you could have copied the contents of script.php, pasted it twice more, hardcoded the `$start` and `$end` values in each section, and added a `sleep(5)` between each copy/paste. That's the whole script.

Comment: best way I think is to retrieve all the products you need in a global array then slice it, write data into separate files and you're done.This only need one sql query

Answer (score 92):

use:

```
sleep(NUMBER_OF_SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 39):

before starting your actions, use

```
 sleep(5);
```

Answer (score 13):

or:

```
usleep(NUMBER_OF_MICRO_SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 3):

In Jan2018 the only solution worked for me:

```
<?php

if (ob_get_level() == 0) ob_start();
for ($i = 0; $i<10; $i++){

    echo "<br> Line to show.";
    echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";    

    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep(2);
}

echo "Done.";

ob_end_flush();
```

?>

Answer (score 3):

i use this

```
    $i = 1;
    $last_time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    while($i > 0){
        $total = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - $last_time;
        if($total >= 2){
            // Code Here
            $i = -1;
        }
    }
```

you can use

```
function WaitForSec($sec){
    $i = 1;
    $last_time = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'];
    while($i > 0){
        $total = $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'] - $last_time;
        if($total >= 2){
            return 1;
            $i = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and run code =>

```
WaitForSec(your_sec);
```

Example :

```
WaitForSec(5);
```

**OR** 
you can use sleep

Example :

```
sleep(5);
```

Comment: Why writing a custom function if there is a built in one that performs the same function ? 
Someone may down vote your answer for this ....

Comment: My shared hosting prohibits / disables php sleep(). Thanks @kha

Comment: @kha `$_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']` produced an infinite loop on my shared hosting. I switched to `$now = time();
    while ($now + 4 > time()) {
        // do nothing
    }`

Answer (score 0):

> I am on shared hosting, so I can't do a lot of queries otherwise I get a blank page.

That sounds very peculiar. I've got the cheapest PHP hosting package I could find for my last project - and it does not behave like this. I would not pay for a service which did. Indeed, I'm stumped to even know how I could configure a server to replicate this behaviour.

Regardless of why it behaves this way, adding a sleep in the middle of the script cannot resolve the problem.

Since, presumably, you control your product catalog, new products should be relatively infrequent (or are you trying to get stock reports?). If you control when you change the data, why run the scripts automatically? Or do you mean that you already have these URLs and you get the expected files when you run them one at a time?

Comment: he may be getting blank results because he's not freeing up results after executing each query

Answer (score -3):

In https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.usleep.php

```
<?php
// Wait 2 seconds
usleep(2000000);

// if you need 5 seconds
usleep(5000000);
?>
```

Comment: foreach is unnecessary,and delay isn't a function in PHP that I'm aware of.